# Is there a more specific verb for "getting" cancer?

Tags: verbs

Other than saying somebody "got" cancer, is there a more commonly accepted verb I can use? I thought of the verb *contract*, whose definition (according to a google search) is

> catch or develop (a disease or infectious agent).

Though a separate google search for "Can somebody contract cancer" gives negative answers that go on to explain that cancer is not contagious. This was not news to me, but it does seem to indicate that *contract* is more commonly regarded as analogous to *catch* as in "She caught the flu", which I would never use to describe getting cancer.

My question is, is *contract* a commonly accepted verb for getting cancer, or is there a better one in common usage, other than *get*?

Comment: What's wrong with *develop* (the verb besides *catch* in your definition of *contract*)? Googling, we find *Most people who develop cancer have no family history of the disease* and *Mutations build up over time, which is why people tend to develop cancer later in life* among the numerous instances of "develop cancer".

Comment: @PeterShor. Nothing is wrong with it other than the fact I didn't think of it. Feel free to post it as an actual answer if you want

Comment: "[having a problem with cancer](https://youtu.be/dIy72gMVWxM?t=52)" has stuck with me since I first heard it in 2001 (emotional scene warning). It of course may not be clear or suit your purpose, but it might suggest some alternatives depending on context.

Comment: Depending on the purpose and context, *to be diagnosed with* cancer is a good substitute, though obviously the meaning and focus is a bit different.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The word besides *get* that seems most common associated with cancer is *develop*.

Googling "develop(ed) cancer", we find

> Most people who develop cancer have no family history of the disease,
> Mutations build up over time, which is why people tend to develop cancer later in life,
> They also couldn't tell me why I developed cancer in the first place,
> The fact that your pet developed cancer is not unusual.

Let me note that "contract cancer" is not unusual, and doesn't mean that cancer is contagious. However, the word *contract* seems to be generally associated with a discussion of the cause of the cancer:

> Van Halen believes he contracted cancer because of the metal guitar pick he would cradle in his mouth on stage.
>
> A court has ruled that a woman who is terminally ill from an asbestos cancer contracted the disease from washing her husband's work overalls.